# PHP RegEx Excluding TWO strings from string

Tags: php, trim, regex-negation, truncate

After searching various other questions in order attempt solving this on my own, I've gotten this far yet I cannot figure out how add an additional string.

```
// $url will actually be $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$url = "/folder123/?id=foo"; // it could be "index.php?id=foo"

preg_replace_callback('#^/folder123/#', function($match) {
    return $match[1];
}, $url);
```

**Expected Result:** ?id=foo

With my current code, I'll get the expected result; however I don't know how to also check for index.php. My intention is to have the string exclude these two parts.

Comment: Without context it's difficult to help you. Why are you trying to exclude index.php or folder123? I think it'd be just easier to access `$_GET`

Comment: Do you have to use ‍‍`RegEx`? You can also use other functions

Comment: for example : $url = "/index.php/?id=foo";
echo substr($url ,  strpos($url, '?'))

Comment: @Mike There may not be any GET variables in some addresses so that wouldn't be suitable. No need for additional context as I'm not looking for alternative solutions that may not work out in all cases.

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi I prefer to use RegEx since it appears to be the most efficient. If you have something else in mind with the same end-result, please suggest.

Comment: test this :   preg_replace_callback('/(\?|\&).*/', function($match) {
        var_dump($match[0]) ;
    }, $url);

Comment: Adding a ^ before /(\?|\&).*/ did the trick! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match them both you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) followed by `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

[`^(?:/folder123/|index\.php)\K.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/TuIVAQ/1)

```
preg_replace_callback('#^(?:/folder123/|index\.php)\K.*$#', function($match) { return $match[0]; }, $url);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bD61J)

Comment: @theflarenet This is another demo without the `\K` but with a capturing group which will be returned in the callback. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/HvBYZ). Now `preg_replace_callback` actually returns the matched group with the value `?id=foo` Shall I update my answer with that one?

Comment: I'm not too sure honestly because I see the same end result, but perhaps you are right--considering that this one may be more appropriate since it's a one-for-one returned value.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help you :

```
$url = "index.php?id=foo22"; // it could be "index.php?id=foo"

preg_replace_callback('/(\?|\&).*/', function($match) {
    var_dump($match[0]) ;
}, $url);
```

Comment: This works! However, it needs a ^ before the regular expression. Thanks!